# integer constants behaving as class objects

Tags: c#

How does the integer 4 in the following code behave as a class\struct??

```
class main
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(4.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's boxed to System.Int32 then it's an object with its properties/methods.

Comment: In C# this is Automatic Conversion of Type

Comment: Actually, I think ToString is called directly on the int structure without boxing, and the resulting string, which is a special class in .net, is passed to the writeline method.  *edit* After some googling on valuetype methods, I found this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/stuart_fujitani/boxnunbox11192005055746am/boxnunbox.aspx , halfway on the page (just search on tostring), it seems to confirm that calling 4.ToString would prevent boxing (while writeline(4) would cause boxing)

Comment: Well but 4 is nothing but an integer constant. How could you use it as a structure or a class and invoke functions on it?

Answer (score 4):

#### --- UPDATE ---

Actually, I think @Me.Name could be right. The `System.Int32` implements `ToString`, so it can be called directly. There is no need for boxing in this case.

If I were to pass a `System.Int32` to a method that expects an `object` parameter, then it would be boxed.

#### --- OLD ANSWER ---

It is [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) on the fly.

Quite from MSDN: *"Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type."*

Comment: But it is said that the class types are accessed through reference and value types are accessed directly and in this case it appears that the value types are also accessed through reference..

Comment: @user1232138 Yes, that's the purpose of boxing. A value type is converted to object which is then accessed through reference.